# Consulta XPath usando fechas

Tags: xml, xpath

Tengo el siguiente archivo xml

```xml
<clientes>
    <cliente>
        <nombre>
            Juan Martinez
        </nombre>
        <fecha_inicio>
            2016-10-2
        </fecha_inicio>
    </cliente>
    <cliente>
        <nombre>
            Jose Gonzalez
        </nombre>
        <fecha_inicio>
            2014-8-2
        </fecha_inicio>
    </cliente>
</clientes>
```

`fecha_inicio` es la fecha en que se registro el cliente en la empresa.

Y quiero una consulta XPath que retorne los nombres de clientes que tengan mas de un año de antigüedad en la empresa.

Osea algo así:

```
/clientes/cliente[fecha_inicio > 1 año]/nombre
```

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con que tengan más de un año de fecha de inicio?

Comment: Fecha de inicio sería la fecha en que se registró ese cliente en la empresa.
Quiero los nombres de los clientes que tengan mas de un año de antigüedad

Comment: ¿Osea que tenga una fecha que no sea errónea no?

Comment: Acabo de editar mi pregunta, espero que la entiendas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si te es posible cambiar el XML para formatear las fechas con dos dígitos tanto el mes como el día, y lo dejas así:

```
<clientes>
    <cliente>
        <nombre>
            Juan Martinez
        </nombre>
        <fecha_inicio>
            2016-10-02
        </fecha_inicio>
    </cliente>
    <cliente>
        <nombre>
            Jose Gonzalez
        </nombre>
        <fecha_inicio>
            2014-08-02
        </fecha_inicio>
    </cliente>
</clientes>
```

Entonces puedes hacer esto:

```
/clientes/cliente[(current-date() - xs:date(fecha_inicio)) > xs:dayTimeDuration('P365D') ]
```

Lo cual en este caso devuelve esto:

```
<cliente>
        <nombre>
            Jose Gonzalez
        </nombre>
        <fecha_inicio>
            2014-08-02
        </fecha_inicio>
    </cliente>
```